# programmatically adding categories to custom taxonomy

Tags: categories

wp_create_category() adds new categories to the 'content' taxonomy associated with the post type...

Simple question really neither wp_create_category() or wp_insert_category() allows configuration for taxonomy type... so how can I can do it?

Comment: What is the use case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For custom taxonomies you should use [wp_insert_term()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term)